# Why does my click function with 2 selectors needs 2 clicks?

Tags: jquery, click, toggle

I want to run a toggle function for 2 selectors. I have an element with class `.rgstr` and another one with class `.disable` which are my selectors.

Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.rgstr, .disable').click(function() {
        var clicks = $(this).data('clicks');

        if (!clicks) {
            $('.loginpanel').animate({ right: "0"}, 300, function() {
                $('.lgnreg > div').stop().animate({right:"0"},1200,'easeOutExpo');
            });
            $('.disable').css("display","block");
        } 
        else {
            $('.loginpanel').animate({ right: "-300px" }, 250, 'easeInOutCirc', function() {
                $('.lgnreg > div').stop().animate({right:"-25px"},250,'easeInOutCirc');
            });
            $('.disable').css("display","none");
        }
        $(this).data("clicks", !clicks);
    });
});
```

HTML :

```
<div class="disable"></div>
<div class="rgstr">
    <a href="#">Login/Register</a >
</div>
<div class="loginpanel">
<div class="lgnreg">
    <div class="login">
        <form>
            <input type="text" name="lgnusername" id="lgnusername" value="Username" />
            <input type="text" name="lgnpassword" id="lgnpassword" value="Password" />
            <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Login" />
        </form>
    </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

I want when the `.rgstr` is clicked, `.loginpanel` be opened and then when we click on `.disable`, be closed. Now it works, but with 2 clicks. First time I click on `.rgstr` the `.loginpanel` gets opened, but then I have to click twice on `.disable` to close `.loginpanel`, and same for the next times. How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you please include a snippet of your HTML code too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `'clicks'` data element is only on the element you *clicked on*, not on *both* elements.

So, when you click on `.rgstr`, only it's data is updated, not `.disable`'s.  When `.disable` is clicked the 1st time, its `clicks` is `undefined`, so the 1st `if` block is ran (just like when you 1st clicked on `.rgstr`).

You need to save the `clicks` variable somewhere where both elements can read/write the same value.

Comment: but I have put this : var clicks = $(this).data('clicks');
$(this) belongs to both selectors.

Comment: @Pay4m: No it doesn't.  `$(this)` is only the element you clicked on that time, not all the elements the event was bound to.

Comment: so how can I rewrite my code to fix this? can you please guide me ?

Comment: @Pay4m: In the click handler `this` is the element clicked on, so it may be different each time.  You need to save the variable somewhere where it's the same each time.  You can use a global variable (declared outside the handler), or attach the data to a *specific* element (`$('.disable:eq(0)').data('clicks')`).

Comment: wow thanks, I added same classes to both elements, and then replaced this code with the old one:  `var clicks = $('.sameclass').data('clicks');`
it works now,Thank you so much

Comment: @Pay4m: `$('.sameclass').data('clicks')` works because it's the same as `$('.sameclass:eq(0)').data('clicks')`.  `$('.sameclass')` contains more than one element, so when reading data, jQuery just takes the 1st element from the set.